# Change Height of UITableView Customcell

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitableview

I have implemented UITableView with Custom cell,

What i want to do is, i want to change height `UITableViewCell` according to text length,(Dynamic height)

here is my code snippet,

```
#define FONT_SIZE 14.0f
#define CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH 320.0f
#define CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN 10.0f


- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    NSString *text = [DescArr objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH - (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2), 20000.0f);
    CGSize size = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    CGFloat height = MAX(size.height, 55.0);

    return height;
}
```

Height of `UITableViewCell` changes properly but the height of CustomCell does not change,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"BTSTicketsCellIdentifier";
    CRIndCoupnCell *cell = (CRIndCoupnCell *)[tblDescriptn dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CRIndCoupnCell" owner:self options:nil];
        for (id oneObject in nib) if ([oneObject isKindOfClass:[CRIndCoupnCell class]])
            cell = (CRIndCoupnCell *)oneObject;
    }

    NSLog(@"cell.frame.size.height=%f",cell.frame.size.height);

    cell.lblleft.text=[arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.lblRight.text=[DescArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

My Log shows `cell.frame.size.height=100.0` in all the rows. height of CustomCell doesn't change.

[image]:
Where am i making mistake ? please help.

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: make sure the custom cell identifier you are using is correct

Comment: yes, it is correct data is coming but height of the cell is not proper.

Comment: can u print height in this  CGFloat height = MAX(size.height, 55.0);

Comment: Log shows: `55`,`90`,`55`,`55` chk this: http://i.imgur.com/niBfSQ7.png

Comment: and ur static cell height

Comment: ok it shows that ur cell height is changing but it is not sufficient just add extra height manually to the height while returning height

Comment: sometimes i have one line data. in that cell i don't want this big height

Comment: check lblRight height

Comment: shows lblRight height fixed: 89.0

Comment: check  height CGFloat height = MAX(size.height, 55.0);

Comment: Replace the 55 to 2000.0f, and your problem solve

Comment: i dont want fixed height 2000

Comment: see i want do this way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18527227/uitableviewcell-with-dynamic-height-ios/18527283?noredirect=1#comment27248513_18527283

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are constraining the string to size of the full width of cell minus 2 times the cell margin and a max height of 2000 but since you are setting the string as text of the label with green colored text color, you should rather check for the size according to that label's width and an arbitrary height of 2000 or anything of your choice.

```
CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(MYGREENLABEL_WIDTH, 2000);
```

Comment: wrote this in `heightForRowAtIndexPath` still not working
   `static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"BTSTicketsCellIdentifier";
    CRIndCoupnCell *cell = (CRIndCoupnCell *)[tblDescriptn dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    NSString *text = [DescArr objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(cell.lblRight.frame.size.height, 2000.0f);
    CGSize size = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    CGFloat height = MAX(size.height, 200.0f);
    return height;`

Comment: Dont put this code in `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method. Just check your `lblRight` frame from nib and put its width where in setting constraint size, thats it

Comment: where to set `lblRight` frame ? in which method ?

Comment: Do that in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method only. That is the method for showing the particular cell's view on given index paths.