# Dynamic cell height for tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am working on UITableView and the cells have different contents like a Facebook cell, so how can i change the height of each cell accordingly?

Comment: use `heightForRowAtIndexPath:`

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18527227/uitableviewcell-with-dynamic-height-ios

U need to do some googling before posting out question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Should follow the link http://www.raywenderlich.com/73602/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-auto-layout This is best way to achieve to do this

Answer (score 0):

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:20];
NSDictionary *userAttributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: font,
                             NSForegroundColorAttributeName:         [UIColor blackColor]};
NSString *text = @"Your label text";

CGSize textSize = [text sizeWithAttributes: userAttributes];

ht = 20;

if (textSize.width > [FunctionUtils getViewWidth]) {

ht = (textSize.width/([FunctionUtils getViewWidth]));
ht = (ceil(ht))*20+35;
//20 font size
}

return ht;
}
```