# I need to set UITableViewCell Dynamic Height, With Multiple dynamic label with UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uilabel

I need to set `UITableViewCell` dynamic height based on it's content.

Here is my demo image:

[image]

In this to label which have dynamic content so based on that label content my cell height should change..

I get the constraint error. In this cell two UILabel is available and both have dynamic content size. (I already make the demo with auto resizing cell with only one label.) But in this cell two label are there. So error is xcode suggest me to give Y POS or Height to label, but I already set top constraints. (4 side constraints with label line set to 0 Zero) But still it's fails.
I also try with this code

```
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 250.0;
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```

Here is my [demo code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/u53a8198j1g6uq6/commentDemo%202.zip?dl=0)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UITableViewCell with dynamic height iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18527227/uitableviewcell-with-dynamic-height-ios)

Comment: Include the code **in the question itself**, not on some external resource.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I4jSwWmqfOA check this tutorial @NiravS

Comment: your lable number of line should be zero

Answer (score 7):

Look at the screenshot of my output. For both the labels , you should give all the four constrains and you have to change the heights of both the labels priority to 750 & set the hugging and resistance priority to 1000. Then you have to change the number of lines to 0 in storyboard

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

        return 250

    }
```

[image]

Comment: you have to change the heights of both the labels priority to 750, I did not get this - Please clarify on this

Answer (score 0):

Add this code into `viewDidLoad()` method:

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44
```

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 3, Use

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    return HEIGHT // Maximum cell height
}
```

In table view cell, Set dynamic height constraint to the text view (Greater than or equal) - Maximum text view height

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. After setting text to  `UILabel`, it doesn't still set correct height frame to its content. In `cellForRowAt`, just add this:

```
//these make height frame both of labels became correct

cell.lbName.sizeToFit()
cell.lbAge.sizeToFit()

// update cell layout
cell.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at the `UITableViewDelegate` function `tableView(_:heightForRowAt:)`. It’ll work in your case if you are able to calculate the height for a given index path.